# android: relative layout two buttons occupy all the available horizontal space

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a relative layout and i have two buttons in it with texts "hello" and "world" respectively. i want these two buttons to lie adjacent to each other and equally occupy the whole horizontal space available.

i tried the following but didnt get expected output

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

     <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"      android:text="@string/world" android:id="@+id/world"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/hello"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
  />  


       <Button
          android:id="@+id/hello"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="@string/hello"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

i tried changing the android:layout_width of both children to fill_parent but that didnt work too.

i have a working solution of using LinearLayout with layout_weight set to 0.5 on both childs but i wanted to understand if there is way to do that in relative layout itself.

thanks,

Comment: You seem to have a solution already - what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Use the LinearLayout with the layout_weight. That's the accepted way to do it.

Comment: I think there is an answer better than the one you have selected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this with `RelativeLayout`. Try `LinearLayout` and the `layout_weight` attribute.

Answer (score 36):

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:text="First" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
        android:text="Second" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Check]

#### Note:

- Even if the `android:layout_width` was `fill_parent` the result will not change.
- What actually matters here is `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft`

Comment: I'm curious why does this work in a RelativeLayout. Why did the buttons occupy more than what it needs (wrap_content)?

Comment: @dannyroa the `android:layout_width` doesn't matter, even if it was `fill_parent` the results will not change, what actually matters is `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

Comment: I guess this has to do with the layout logic of the RelativeLayout. But this is a nice hack around it.

Comment: for versions greater than 16, you also need to add android:layout_alignParentStart="true" and android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

Answer (score 5):

I know that is a old request, but maybe it's can be useful for somebody.

In your case the right solution is using Linear Layout. But for reply your request and suppose that you have an other widget in your layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdescription"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="description here"/>

 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvdescription">

    <Button          
        android:id="@+id/world"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="0dp"      
        android:text="@string/world"
        android:weight="1"
    />  
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try implementing LinearLayout(horizontal) and then set android:layout_weight="1" for both buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int height = metrics.heightPixels;
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
```

in relative layout you can achieve this dynamically.

```
Button1.setWidth(width / 2);
Button2.setWidth(width / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a Button align it in center with `1dp` `width` and `height`. Now place your Button1 with the property `android:layout_width = fill parent` `to left of center`, again with respect to center button put Button2 to the `right of center` with the property `android:layout_width = fill parent`.